# mysql output showing "\r\n\r\n" and "\" when using double quote and paragraphing. How to get rid?

Tags: php, mysql

I have built a html form and i'm using PHP to insert data into my phpmyadmin database. Every time i type in text data into the textarea as shown below:

Input in textarea field

[image]

The output show like this when i use mysql to retrieve the data from the database.

Output in textarea field

[image]

Below is my mysql insert code after form submission:

```
<?php
> if(isset($_POST['submit']))       {
> 
> $remarks = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["remarks"]);
> 
> $stmtinsert = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO
> patient_continuation(REMARKS) 
>            VALUES (?);");
> 
>           mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmtinsert, "s", $remarks); 
>           mysqli_stmt_execute($stmtinsert); 
> 
> }
?>
```

Below is the the data retrieval code:

```
<?php
$stmtquery = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM patient_continuation WHERE ID =?;");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmtquery, "s", $con_id);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmtquery);
$result = $stmtquery->get_result();
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();

?>

<label><b>Continuation Sheet </b></label>
<textarea class="form-control" tabindex="3" name="remarks" id="remarks" rows="12"><?php echo $row['REMARKS'];?></textarea>
```

Can anyone help  resolve this issue as my forms use many textarea field?

Comment: Please include the code which marshals the output from MySQL into the text area.

Comment: You can use htmlspecialchars_decode() function when insert data in database.

Comment: 1) Make sure your server is not configured with `magic_quotes_gpc` (note: it **really** shouldn't). 2) Use a prepared statement with bound parameters to insert the data **as received** into your database. 3) Use `nl2br()` on the output when displaying it. If the text should not contain HTML, also use `htmlspecialchars()`

Comment: @Les88 use 'if(isset($_POST['submit'])) { $remarks = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, htmlspecialchars_decode($_POST["remarks"]) );

Comment: @rawathemant still doesn't work, i'm still getting the \ and \r\n\r\n when i retrieve the output with mysql.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen , i have posted my code on top. Pls see if you can help. thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace this code `$remarks = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["remarks"]);` with `$remarks = $_POST["remarks"];`. You don't need to escape the input if you use prepared statements.

When outputting escape the html:
`<?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['REMARKS']);?>`.

This should do the trick. 
Note the latter escaping will not support HTML tags in the text.

Comment: finally its working after numerous trial and error. Thanks!